# employees by JobTitle and Gender

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to figure out how many employees I have by job title (example: doctor) and gender. I'm not sure where to start.
I'm using Adventure Works in SQL 2008

Comment: "I'm not sure where to start." Hint: Please do not **start** solving your problem by posting a description of your problem on an online help forum.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic query and I think @bernie is right - you shouldn't START by coming here telling us what you need to do. You should at the very least also include what you've already tried.

```
SELECT JobTitle, Gender, [count] = COUNT(*)
  FROM HumanResources.Employee
  GROUP BY JobTitle, Gender
  ORDER BY JobTitle, Gender;
```

Note that there are no doctors in the database.

If you just want a count for a *specific* job title and *specific* gender, then:

```
DECLARE @JobTitle NVARCHAR(50), @Gender NCHAR(1);

SELECT @JobTitle = N'Accountant', @Gender = N'F';

SELECT [count] = COUNT(*)
  FROM HumanResources.Employee
  WHERE JobTitle = @JobTitle
    AND Gender = @Gender;
```